# Found 0 keys for the service guid provided

Tags: visual-recognition, watson-studio

I followed that [tutorial](https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/detect-wildfire-damaged-homes-using-drone-images-watson-visual-recognition/) , the VR training resulted in this error:

```
Error encountered while training.

Error in Watson Visual Recognition service: Found 0 keys for the service guid provided
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would indicate a problem with your service account or instance. You will need to open a support ticket with IBM cloud support